# Wolfram Alpha is giving two different results for the same computation - why?

Tags: normal-distribution, convolution, wolfram-alpha, rectangles, gaussian

I'm exploring the convolution of a rectangle function scaled by a factor of $\displaystyle{n}$ with a Gaussian function/standard normal distribution of varying parameters (example [1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=convolve+%28rectangle+function%2C+a*e%5E%28-x%5E2%29%29), [2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=convolve+%28rectangle+function%2C+e%5E%28-%28x-b%29%5E2%29%29), [3](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=convolve+%28rectangle+function%2C+e%5E%28-c*x%5E2%29%29)) using Wolfram Alpha. Unfortunately, Wolfram Alpha seems to return inconsistent results:

[Result 1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=convolve+%28n*rectangle+function%2C+gaussian%29+for+n%3D%7B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%2C+5%2C+6%2C+7%2C+8%2C+9%2C+10%7D)

vs.

[Result 2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=convolve+%28n*rectangle+function%2C+e%5E%28-x%5E2%29%29+for+n%3D%7B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%2C+5%2C+6%2C+7%2C+8%2C+9%2C+10%7D)

Wolfram Alpha confirms mathematically equivalent inputs, i.e. a scaled unit box function as the first function and a Gaussian function/standard normal distribution as the second function. However, the output is different - note the different power of $\displaystyle{n}$:

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{{2}}{n}^{2}{\left({e}{r} f{{\left(\frac{{\mu-{y}+\frac{1}{{2}}}}{{\sqrt{{{2}}}\sigma}}\right)}}-{e}{r} f{{\left(\frac{{\mu-{y}-\frac{1}{{2}}}}{{\sqrt{{{2}}}\sigma}}\right)}}\right)}$

vs.

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{{2}}{n}\sqrt{{\pi}}{\left({e}{r} f{{\left(\frac{1}{{2}}-{y}\right)}}+{e}{r} f{{\left({y}+\frac{1}{{2}}\right)}}\right)}$

How is this possible?

The question was how a constant scaling of the rectangle function effects the convolution. My expectation was a constant scaling of the convolved function, i.e. result 2, but Wolfram Alpha gives a quadratic scaling in result 1.

Comment: If I enter gaussian to wolfram alpha I don't get $e^{-x^2}$

Comment: Well one issue is that e^{-x^2} is not the same function as the gaussian pdf.

Comment: @Fakemistake: I'm looking at different Gaussians incl. the standard normal distribution (but not exclusively). Wolfram Alpha interprets "Gaussian" as the standard normal distribution, but I'm looking at general Gaussian functions with different parameters

Comment: @AaronHendrickson: Yes, I'm looking at different Gaussians to see how the parameters "carry over" to the convolved equation (I need to parametrize the convolution with physical values, that's why)

Comment: In any case, using one Gaussian over the other should not introduce an additional factor of $\displaystyle{n}$ as Wolfram Alpha suggests in the first link, this cannot be right! $\displaystyle{n}$ is just a constant and also not part of the Gaussian, but comes attached to the rectangle function. The convolution should be "blind" to it: $\displaystyle{\left[{c}\cdot f{{\left({x}\right)}}\right]}\ast g{{\left({x}\right)}}={c}\cdot{\left[ f{{\left({x}\right)}}\ast g{{\left({x}\right)}}\right]}$

Answer (score 0):

As others have said these are **not** "the same calculation". The Gaussian is the **integral** of $e^{-x^2}$, not $e^{-x^2}$ itself.

Comment: No, $\displaystyle{e}^{{-{x}^{2}}}$ is an example of a [Gaussian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function). What you are referring to is the [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral), which is what I'm *actually* interested in, as above convolution can be represented as the difference of two [error functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Integral_of_error_function_with_Gaussian_density_function), see Wolfram Alpha outputs in the question

Comment: WA interprets "gaussian" as the Gaussian pdf with mean mu and standard deviation sigma. It does not interpret "gaussian" as the integral of exp(-x^2)

Comment: @david the problem here is that WA interprets "gaussian" as the normal pdf. Yes, exp(-x^2) is sometimes called a gaussian function but it is not the same as the gaussian pdf. Just look at the links you provided. WA tells you how it interprets the output at the top of the page.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson: Yes, "gaussian" is interpreted as the standard normal distribution. But the normal distribution differs from $\displaystyle{e}^{{-{x}^{2}}}$ only by a constant and this should not change the dependency on $\displaystyle{n}$, which is the scaling factor for the rectangle function. $\displaystyle{n}$ really is not related in any way to the Gaussian/normal distribution, one would expect it to just "carry over". Wolfram, however, adds $\displaystyle{n}^{2}$ to one of the computations

Comment: In fact, one should be able to plug in *anything* for the second function (anything that doesn't depend on $\displaystyle{n}^{}$) without any effect on the power of $\displaystyle{n}^{}$ in the result

Comment: @david they differ by more than a constant since the standard gaussian pdf has an exp(-x^2/2) in it. The n^2 bit is puzzling at the moment.

Comment: True, there is also the scaling of the exponent. But as you say, this $\displaystyle{n}^{2}$ is what throws me off. I was going to take it as a constant and just plugged it into Wolfram Alpha for fun...argh

Comment: @david the issues seems to be how WA interprets your input. Using your example, if you input "convolve (n*rectangle function, gaussian)" into WA you get the correct result.

Comment: Okay, that then at least confirms the correct output. Thx

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer. Just posting what Mathematica gives for comparison since the commands given are not left to interpretation (as is the case with WA)

Command:

Convolve[n UnitBox[x],Exp[-x^2],x,y]

Result:
$$
\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } n
   \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{1}{2}-y\right)+\text{erf}\left(y+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)
$$

Command:

Convolve[n UnitBox[x],PDF[ NormalDistribution[[Mu],[Sigma]],x],x,y]

Result:
$$
\frac{1}{2} n \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{-2 \mu +2 y+1}{2 \sqrt{2} \sigma
   }\right)+\text{erf}\left(\frac{2 \mu -2 y+1}{2 \sqrt{2} \sigma }\right)\right)
$$

You can copy and paste these commands into WA to verify.

Edit: It looks like for the second one WA prefers if you write Convolve[n UnitBox[x],gaussian,x,y].  Either way there is no n^2 in the answer.